# how to fix error field to transform "c:/user/..." on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

i add an library to my gradle project and after that when i try to run it a i face to this error

```
    Failed to transform 'C:\Users\17r\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.core\jersey-common\2.29.1\ea60b9ace56f1ae758c2eebbb48e8387d959102f\jersey-common-2.29.1.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
```

and the library that i add it to gradle is

```
    implementation "org.telegram:telegrambots:4.7"
```

any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i disable jetifier and it work for me
in gradle.properties i change this

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

to

```
android.enableJetifier=false
```

and it work